# MySQL Restore Large Dump

Tags: mysql, restore

I have a dump file of a single table which is 7GB. I try to restore it using

```
mysql -u root -p DB_NAME < .SQL FILE
```

But I don't see any activities in task manager. CPU is 00 and RAM is 5,700 K. I don't know if it is really restoring it or and error occurred. Is there any other way to restore this? I am running it on windows 7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this answer, let's use /root/MySQLData.sql as the SQL File.

Go into mysql via the client and run it like this:

```
mysql> source /root/MySQLData.sql
```

Give it a Try !!!

**UPDATE 2011-12-16 21:08 EDT**

I just caught on to your problem: Your program is not running because you did not supply the password. It is stuck in the background waiting for a password. That's your actual problem. Kill the job and run it again with the password on the command line:

```
mysql -u root -ppassword DB_NAME < .SQL FILE
```

or just use my original submitted answer up above.

**UPDATE 2011-12-19 11:40 EDT**

*I just re-read the question. You said single table. Then it hit me !!!*

You need to ramp up your [**bulk_insert_buffer_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_bulk_insert_buffer_size). The default is 8M.

To see what your current setting is, run this:

```
mysql> show variables like 'bulk%';
```

Just add this to /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
bulk_insert_buffer_size=512M
```

So as to not restart mysql, run this SQL command:

```
SET GLOBAL bulk_insert_buffer_size = 1024 * 1024 * 512;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thanx man, but I entered the password. Actually it is done. But its too much for a server with 24GB Ram. I don't know. Thanx anyway.

Comment: @Rolando, Is there any calculation for ```bulk_insert_buffer_size``` based on table size?

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql -u root -p

set global net_buffer_length=1000000; --Set network buffer length to a large byte number

set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000; --Set maximum allowed packet size to a large byte number

SET foreign_key_checks = 0; --Disable foreign key checking to avoid delays,errors and unwanted behaviour

source /path/folder/database_forum_.sql 


SET foreign_key_checks = 1; --Remember to enable foreign key checks when procedure is complete!
```